# How do I use pom.xml profile properties with pom aggregation?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am using a pom.xml to aggregate various builds. I'd like to setup profiles with settings that apply to multiple pom.xml files. So, I have something like

```
<project>
....
<modules>
  <module>project1</module>
  <module>project2</module>
</modules>
<profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>local</id>
     <properties>
        <my.setting>setting</my.setting>
     </properties>
   <profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

However, my.setting doesn't seem to get put into the child modules. How do get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using only aggegration. But you must use inheritance in the child modules which means to have a parent entry in there. Then the information will be propagated to the childs.